# How to have, in a link, a button that is not a link

Tags: html

I have a div representing a panel that acts as a link. This panel contains a button that triggers some Javascript.

How can I do so that the button does not activates that link ?

```
<a href="/some/page">
    <div>
        ...
        <button onClick="someFunction()">Click</button>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You can't; it's invalid HTML to nest one interactive element within another.

Comment: I'm by no means a web dev professionals, but one approach that comes to my mind is to remove the button from the panel, make it as it's own element, and use `position: fixed` to overlay it on the panel. Again, not a web dev professional, so take that suggestion with a heavy grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

`<a href="/some/page" onclick="return false;">Click me</a>`

this will prevent the default action.